# ApiController.RedirectToRoute Using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an API that returns a `RedirectToRoute`.  I have noticed that it will want to fall back to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Is it possible to make this work with HTTP or HTTPS depending on the original request?

Like if the link is `http://example.com/api/myaction` then myaction's result would use HTTP.  Of course if it were `https://example.com/api/myaction` then the result would use HTTPS.

Comment: `I have noticed that it will want to fall back to HTTP instead of HTTPS.` <= can you share the code where this occurs?

Comment: Certainly.
 
`userGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
return this.RedirectToRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", new { controller = "User", action = "ChangeLogin", userGuid });`